# How to write Qunit for attachEventBrowser in UI5

Tags: sapui5, sinon, qunit, stub

I have a code snippet for which I have to increase code coverage
Following is my controller-

I need to have statements in my qunit for the bold section

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
     "sap/m/MessageToast",
], function (Controller,JSONModel,MessageToast) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("com.sap.onesm.supplier.ext.slpCard.supplierContactDetails.Main", {
        onInit: function () {
            let cardState={};
            this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(cardState), "cardState");

            let oEventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
            oEventBus.subscribe("SLPDataChannel", "loadData", this.loadData, this);
            console.log('Supplier contact subscribe.');
            oEventBus.subscribe("SLPDataChannel", "errorData", this.errorData, this);
            let cardSubscribeData = {
                "card": 'supplierContact',
                "subscribed": true
            };
            oEventBus.publish("CardSubscribeChannel", "callVendorAPI", cardSubscribeData);
            setTimeout(()=>this.getAvatarWidth(),100);
        },
        loadData: function(channelId, eventId, oData) {
            console.log('In callback supplierContactDetails.loadData().. ');
            let oController = this;
            var data = oData.vendorData;
            oController.oCard = **oController.getView().getParent().getComponentData().__sapUiIntegration_card;
            oController.oCard.getCardHeader().attachBrowserEvent("click",function(){
                oController.onPressNavToSMContacts(oData.smVendorId, oData.s4Url);
            });**

            let loaderStatus = oController.getView().getModel("cardState");
            if(data[0]!=undefined && data[0]["Primary contact first name"]){
                let name=data[0]["Primary contact first name"];
                name+=data[0]["Primary contact middle name"]? " "+data[0]["Primary contact middle name"]:'';
                name+=data[0]["Primary contact last name"]? " "+data[0]["Primary contact last name"]:'';
                data[0]["contactName"]=name;
                oController.getView().setModel( new JSONModel(data[0]), "supplierContact");
                loaderStatus.setProperty("/status", 1);
            }else{
                loaderStatus.setProperty("/status", 2);
            }
            return data[0];
        },
        errorData: function(channelId, eventId, oData) {
            console.log('In callback supplierContactDetails.errorData().. ');
            let controller = this;
            let oModel = controller.getView().getModel("cardState");
            oModel.setProperty("/status", 3);
            console.log("error for " + oData.smVendorId + " : " + oData.error);
        }
    });
});
```

Following is my test File

```
QUnit.module("Supplier Contacts Card");
    let oController = new SupplierContactController();

    oController.getView = function() {
        return {
            setModel: function(){},
            getModel: function(){
                return {
                    setProperty: function () { }
                }
            },
            getParent: function () { 
                return {
                    getComponentData: function() {
                    }
                }      
            }
            
        };
    };

    QUnit.test("check for data", function(assert) {

        let expectedVendorData = [{"Supplier Name":"Ariba Supplier Risk Demo Supplier 111620",
                                    "SM Vendor ID":"S25187250",
                                    "Primary contact first name": "Drew",
                                    "Primary contact last name": "Myers",
                                    "Primary contact email": "j.drew.myers@gmail.com"}];
        let expectedOData = {"vendorData" : expectedVendorData, 
        "smVendorId": "S25187250", 
        "s4Url": "sampleURL"};

        oController.onInit();
        let loadDataResult = oController.loadData("", "", expectedOData);
        assert.strictEqual(loadDataResult[0][["contactName"]],"Drew Myers","Contact Name Matched");
        assert.strictEqual(loadDataResult[0][["Primary contact email"]],"j.drew.myers@gmail.com","Email Id Matched");
    });
```

I am getting the follwoing error

```
Died on test #1     at QUnit.test (https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/sinon-qunit.js:34:356)
    at http://localhost:8080/test/unit/controller/SupplierContacts.controller.js:27:11
    at https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:10:16806: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__sapUiIntegration_card')@ 1 ms
Expected:   
null
Message:    Diff suppressed as the expected and actual results have an equivalent serialization
Source:     
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__sapUiIntegration_card')
    at p.loadData (http://localhost:8080/ext/slpCard/supplierContactDetails/SupplierContact.controller.js:28:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/test/unit/controller/SupplierContacts.controller.js:39:42)
    at Object.i (https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/sinon.js:220:476)
    at Object.e (https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/sinon.js:220:794)
```

how do I stub attachBrowserEvent

I tried to initialize the controller in this manner

```
let oController = new SupplierContactController();

    oController.getView = function() {
        return {
            setModel: function(){},
            getModel: function(){
                return {
                    setProperty: function () { }
                }
            },
            getParent: function () { 
                return {
                    getComponentData: function() {
                    }
                }      
            }
            
        };
    };
```

but now stuck at getComponentData, don't know what to do after that

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find out what kind of Object is returned by `getCardHeader()`. For this, you can put a debugger point in your original code and check the metadata of the object (put a debugger point on the line and execute:

```
oController.getView().getParent().getComponentData().__sapUiIntegration_card.getCardHeader()
```

Then, knowing what kind of object it is, you can either stub it (create a stub for that object (so `getCardHeader()` would return the stub) and verify that the `attachBrowserEvent` method was called on it or you can just create your own dummy object that contains the method `attachBrowserEvent` if you just want the code to be executed without errors.